# Unity: Get joint rotations of each frame from FBX file

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, fbx, animator

I have some animations stored in FBX files that I need to analyse. I need to know the `localRotation`s and `localPosition`s of each joint for each frame.

My current approach is to use Unity and assign the FBX file to a state in an animation controller and play it. Then I assign a script to the root joint and in each `Update()` call I recursively read the `localRotation` of each joint and save them to a list.

My questions are now:

1. How can I guarantee that I get each frame from the FBX exactly once? Should i use `FixedUpdate` instead of `Update`? I want this script to be not influenced by any load caused by other programs that run in parallel.
2. How can I get the current frame number that is played? How can I detect if the animation has ended or is just being looped?

I need this only to get the joint rotations from the animation. It is not relevant that the animation is actually played on the screen. If there is an easier way, I would also be interested. I want to extract this information from around 200 FBX files that have a length of 2-10 seconds.

I only want to use Unity to process the files, everything else will be done in Python as I have almost no Unity experience.

Comment: If you are going to work in Python why bother with Unity and converting the same data twice at all? You could e.g. have a look at Blender which is open source and written in Python and has an FBX importer which is also already written in Python ;) You can at least look into it and see how they did it ;)

Comment: Thank you. I think it is worth a try. I was able to import the FBX and play it in Blender, but I don't know how to extract the frame information. I guess I need to use the scripting API (bpy) for that? Do you know how to do it?

Comment: What I ment is you can directly look into the source python script of the importer under e.g. `C:\...\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.XX\scripts\addons\import_fbx.py` .. of course it is a bit cluttered with the Blender API but I think you could adopt the according scripts and directly extract the data you need without even having blender installed ;)